# How to integrate GIGYA SWIFT SDK in to react-native project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on react-native 0.60.4 mobile app, where I need to integrate Gigya Swift SDK v1 to my app as a native module of iOS. As, RN creates iOS project using Objective-C and I supposed to integrate the Swift sdk, I don't understand how to add Gigya's active references into `AppDelegate.swift`?

To convert Objective-C project into swift, I added `AppDelegate.swift` and related `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`. Removed default files created by react native `init` command: `AppDelegate.h`, `AppDelegate.m` and `main.m`. Import Gigya framework into project. Added it's references into `AppDelegate.swift`.

To use Gigya's methods, I have created `gigyamanager.swift` and `gigyamanagerbridge.swift`.

Just to confirm this setup will work, created one function into GigyaManager.swift as follow and call `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` in GigyaManagerBridge.h.

I am trying to log the reference from App.js as follow. and result is `undefined`

AppDelegate.swift

```
import Gigya
@objc(AppDelegate)
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
...
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
...
  Gigya.sharedInstance()
  Gigya.sharedInstance(GigyaAccount.self)
  return true
}
```

ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
#import Gigya
```

GigyaManager.swift

```
import Gigya
@objc(GigyaManager)
class GigyaManager: NSObject {
   @objc
  func constantsToExport() -> [AnyHashable : Any]! {
    return ["initialCount": 0]
  }
}
```

GigyaManagerBridge.m

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(GigyaManager, NSObject)
@end
```

App.js

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'
console.log(NativeModules.GigyaManager)
```

I have added Gigya's API key and domain in info.plist file as `string`

Expected result in console should be,

```
initialCount:0
```

And I am getting `undefined`

Is there a way if I can add Gigya's active references into GIgyaManager.swift rether than AppDelegate.swift and allowed to keep default `AppDelegate.m`, `AppDelegate.h` and `main.m`?